Micronaut - Error instantiating bean of type
I'm facing below issue with micronaut while executing tests.
Message: At least one @Introduction method interceptor required, but missing for method: void send(String key,VerificationRequest request). Check if your @Introduction stereotype annotation is marked with @Retention(RUNTIME) and @InterceptorBean(..) with the interceptor type. Otherwise do not load @Introduction beans if their interceptor definitions are missing!

The respective interface where I'm getting error is:
@KafkaClient(id = "sender")
fun interface VerificationSender {

    @Topic("\${$VERIFICATION_TOPIC_NAME_PROPERTY}")
    fun send(@KafkaKey key: String, request: VerificationRequest)
}

Here is the integration test:
@Target(CLASS, FUNCTION)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@MustBeDocumented
@Test
@TagIntegrationTest
annotation class IntegrationTest

The error I'm facing is:
At least one @Introduction method interceptor required, but missing for method: void send(String key,VerificationRequest request). Check if your @Introduction stereotype annotation is marked with @Retention(RUNTIME) and @InterceptorBean(..) with the interceptor type. Otherwise do not load @Introduction beans if their interceptor definitions are missing!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: At least one @Introduction method interceptor required, but missing for method: void send(String key,VerificationRequest request). Check if your @Introduction stereotype annotation is marked with @Retention(RUNTIME) and @InterceptorBean(..) with the interceptor type. Otherwise do not load @Introduction beans if their interceptor definitions are missing!
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.DefaultInterceptorRegistry.resolveToNone(DefaultInterceptorRegistry.java:108)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.DefaultInterceptorRegistry.resolveInterceptors(DefaultInterceptorRegistry.java:71)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.resolveInterceptors(InterceptorChain.java:259)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.resolveInterceptors(InterceptorChain.java:251)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.resolveIntroductionInterceptors(InterceptorChain.java:171)

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Can someone please help on this?

Annotate your class VerifcationRequest with @Serdeable.
Micronaut Serde is very strict and only serialises or deserialises types having that annotation.

I tried that, didnt work.
@Serdeable data class VerificationRequest(val historyId: Long, val reportTimestamp: Instant, val eventId: String)
